# Random number in URL of ASP .NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, random, web

This is my first time having this problem in my ASP .NET C# application. For the past one year during development, it was working fine. But suddenly I noticed that random numbers are generated in the URL. I am very sure that I didn't change any code. How come it become like this?

`172.168.1.20/(S(y40zo0h0pehggfcby4zlrxwt))/LoginPage.aspx`

It should be:

`172.168.1.20/LoginPage.aspx`

`(S(y40zo0h0pehggfcby4zlrxwt))` is randomly generated every time when I debug the application. Anybody has idea what happened? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Anybody has idea what happened?

The ASP.NET application doesn't recognize your User-Agent as supporting cookies and encoding the session identifier in the url instead. You could explicitly force the session to use cookies in your web.config by setting the `cookieless` property to `UseCookies`:

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" ... />
```

You can read more about cookieless sessions in ASP.NET in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx

The same applies to Forms Authentication (not to be confused with ASP.NET Session):

```
<forms cookieless="UseCookies" ... />
```